# Arcgis 10.5 have got problem

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-online-basemaps

Arcgis. Clip. Data managment. Error

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: *shakes head* - "please help me figure out why a crack/pirated piece of software crashes on open".

Comment: Arcgis. Clip. Data managment. Error

Answer (score 3):

This is a known error triggered due to the update on improving ArcGIS Online security using the Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2 connections, affecting products that are connected to ArcGIS Online.

To resolve this you have to install and enable TLS 1.2 on ArcGIS Desktop:

From your tag, I can understand that you are on 10.5.

1. Install the TLS patch for your ArcMap version: https://support.esri.com/en/download/7666#install
2. Once installed navigate to **internet explorer** and check the settings to enable TLS 1.2:

[image]